# can not plot lines in d3, parsing error

Tags: parsing, d3.js

I have the codes on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9qdBD/

I am able to plot out the axises and grid line, but when it comes to the actual line, I got parsing issue. Not sure why. I am probably missing something obvious. Here is the error I got.

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,1LNaN,8LNaN,2LNaN,10LNaN,3LNaN,20LNaN,90"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the [updated, working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/9qdBD/1/)

A couple of things were wrong:

For the x coordinates of the line you had

```
formatter(parser.parse(d.date))
```

First, calling `formatter` on the parsed date produces a String, which is not what you want for plotting values. You need quantitative values of date, so just `parser.parse(d.date)`

Next, you need to to convert each date to an x-position along the x-axis. You had created an x-scale (assigned to the var `x` in your code), which you're using to draw the axis, and you need to use that same scale to convert the dates to the said x-positions:

```
return x(parser.parse(d.date))
```

That fixes the x positions. Then you need to do a similar thing for converting your y values to y positions:

```
return y(d.total)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and edit!! U are awesome! I have one question regards to the ticks. Notice that I have ticks(4), but instead of displaying 4 ticks, it displays 5, and if i lower the number to ticks(3), it displays only 2 ticks. Any idea why?

Comment: The number you pass into `ticks()` is [just a hint](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_ticks). Drawing four ticks here would mean having a tick every 22.5 units (90 divided by 4), which is not "human readable". Ideally d3 would round up to 100 and have a tick every 25 units. Clearly it's choosing not doing it, probably because it doesn't consider 25 to be human readable. One alternative, if your data is static, is to explicitly specify where the ticks should go, using `tickValues()` https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues.

Comment: one more follow up question, sorry~ but it seems giving the parsing error in safari, dont know what is the cause though.